# Hacking the extension.xml in Notes client

Tags: lotus-notes, xpinc

In an XPiNC application parameters are packed into the command line with # rather than ?param=x&param2=y.
Somehow you can edit the extension.xml to accommodate that - I recall having seen that somewhere but I can't find it anymore. Any pointers?